# Define column based on string input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to follow the DRY principle and have found myself wanting to repeat code when there must be a way to assign the string as a variable.

I have a table with 20+ attributes based on languages. I am currently assigning them each in an if statement. Is there a way to assign the language to a string to reference in one statement?

```
if params[:word][:column_name] == "arabic"
  @word.arabic = params[:word][:translation]
end
if params[:word][:column_name] == "chinese"
  @word.chinese = params[:word][:translation]
end
```

Comment: Is this for i18n? There is [a Rails built-in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for that.

Comment: @MarkThomas No it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
@word.send(params[:word][:column_name] + '=', params[:word][:translation])
```

or

```
@word.send("#{params[:word][:column_name]}=", params[:word][:translation])
```

If you are not sure if the column with the name exists, you can do

```
if @word.respond_to?(params[:word][:column_name])
  @word.send(params[:word][:column_name] + '=', params[:word][:translation])
end
```

Comment: Very pretty +1 for multiple approaches